# Writing logs to a file in multithreaded application

Tags: c, multithreading, logging

I've written a server-client application. Now, I have to write what happens on the server to a log file. The server is written in C. I can already write what happens to the screen using printf.

So I'll just have to use fprintf instead of printf. My question is how should I handle the file?

I have `Server.c` source file where there is the main function

Here is the basic structure of my Server application:

**Server.c**

```
//.. some code 
int main(...) {
//some code
//initialize variables
//bind server
//listen server on port
  while(1) 
  {
  //accept client

  int check = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, handle_client,&ctx);//create new thread

  //..
  }//end while
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}//end main
```

`handle_client` is a function which handles clients in a new thread.

How should I make the server log? I will have one text file for example `SERVERLOG.log`, but there are many clients on the server. How should I handle  multiple access to this file?

One way is to create file when I start the server, open it, write in it, close it.
If a client wants to write in the file, then it should open the file to write in it and then close it.

But there is still a problem when more clients want to write in this file....

Comment: I know this a little bit late, but I have edited your question. Even if your English is not so good, the least effort you could have done was to copy paste this in any text processor and fix the simple mistakes, even the browser offers this.

Answer (score 3):

A common solution is to have a `printf`-like function, that writes all output first to a buffer, then locks a semaphore, do the actual writing to file, and unlocks the semaphore. If you are worried about the actual writing being slow, you can instead have a queue where all log messages gets inserted, and let another thread take items from the queue and write them to the file, you still have to protect the queue with e.g. a semaphore, but it should be quicker that doing I/O.

As for the actual file, either open it in the main thread and leave it open. Or if you have a special logging thread with queue then let that thread do the opening. Anyway, you don't need to keep opening/closing it every time you want to write something to it, the important part is to protect it from being written to by multiple threads simultaneous.

Comment: Thx, the only using threads for handle clients is scary enouht for me. So I'll probably use the first advice with semaphores, than handle with another thread.. But I have another question to your firs advice - about the buffer, what if the semaphores is locked? and it's already something in that buffer?

Comment: @user1097772 If you keep the buffer just a local variable (like `char buffer[256]`) then it's effectively local to the thread. If the semaphore is locked, you can either discard the message, wait a little while then discard the message, or just wait until it's the threads turn.

Comment: Or you could just use the existing `printf`-like functions because they already do this. See [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/flockfile.html) which says, "All functions that reference `FILE *` objects shall behave as if they use `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()` internally to obtain ownership of these `FILE *` objects."

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Even then it might not be implemented by all libraries. I've personally seen both `printf` and `fprintf` from different threads to the same file mess things up, and that in VC++.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave it open. Open the log file at server start.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to avoid badly-interlaced output buffers is to use a separate logging process, connected by a pipe (or a named pipe). The logger just sits blocked on the read() from the pipe, and writes whatever it gets to the file. (the reader's stdin, stdout could actually point to the pipe and the file) The clients just write to the pipe (which can have been dup()d over stderr) Writes to a pipe (upto PIPE_BUF) are guaranteed to be atomic.